# Select the nth value of aggregated column after group by in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

Given `df` as follows:

```
  # group value
# 1     A     8
# 2     A     1
# 3     A     7
# 4     B     3
# 5     B     2
# 6     B     6
# 7     C     4
# 8     C     5

df <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), value = c(8L, 
1L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L)), .Names = c("group", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

And a vector of indices (possibly with `NA`):

```
inds <- c(2,1,NA)
```

How we can get the nth element of column `value` per group, **preferably in base R**?

For example, based on `inds`, we want the second element of `value` in group `A`, first element in group `B`, `NA` in group `C`. So the result would be:

```
#[1] 1 3 NA
```

Comment: Is your "data.frame" ordered by the "group" column? You could, just, subset "value" by adding the appropriate offset to `inds`: `df$value[cumsum(c(0, head(tabulate(df$group), -1))) + inds]`

Comment: @alexis_laz Good point but it's not necessarily ordered by the 'group' column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution with `mapply` and `split`:

```
mapply("[", with(df, split(value, group)), inds)
```

which returns a named vector

```
 A  B  C 
 1  3 NA
```

`with(df, split(value, group))` splits the data frame by group and returns a list of data frames. `mapply` takes that list and "inds" and applies the subsetting function "[" to each pairs of arguments.

Comment: very elegant!, I need to get over my aversion to  "[" operator!

Comment: It initially seems awkward to use "[", but it can often avoid the construction of a generic function which probably increases the ease of interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

Using `levels` and `sapply` you could do:

```
DF <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), value = c(8L, 
1L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L)), .Names = c("group", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))


inds <- c(2,1,NA)

lvls = levels(DF$group)

groupInds = sapply(1:length(lvls),function(x) DF$value[DF$group==lvls[x]][inds[x]]  )

groupInds
#[1]  1  3 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using again mapply (but not nearly as elegant as IMO's answer):

```
 mapply(function(x, y) subset(df, group == x, value)[y,] ,levels(df$group), inds)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you said *preferably* in base R, but just for the record, here is a `data.table` way

```
setDT(df)[, .SD[inds[.GRP], value], by=group][,V1]
#[1]  1  3 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did come up with another solution:

```
diag(aggregate(value~group, df, function(x) x[inds])[,-1])
#[1]  1  3 NA
```

---

**Benchmarking**

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
df <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), value = c(8L, 
1L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L)), .Names = c("group", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
inds <- c(2,1,NA)

f_Imo <- function(df) as.vector(mapply("[", with(df, split(value, group)), inds))
f_Osssan <- function(df) {lvls = levels(df$group);sapply(1:length(lvls),function(x) df$value[df$group==lvls[x]][inds[x]])}
f_User2321 <- function(df)  unlist(mapply(function(x, y) subset(df, group == x, value)[y,] ,levels(df$group), inds))
f_dww <- function(df) setDT(df)[, .SD[inds[.GRP], value], by=group][,V1]
f_m0h3n <- function(df) diag(aggregate(value~group, df, function(x) x[inds])[,-1])

all.equal(f_Imo(df), f_Osssan(df), f_User2321(df), f_dww(df), f_m0h3n(df))
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(f_Imo(df), f_Osssan(df), f_m0h3n(df), f_User2321(df), f_dww(df))

# Unit: microseconds
           # expr      min        lq       mean   median        uq      max neval
      # f_Imo(df)   71.004   85.1180   91.52996   91.748   96.8810  121.048   100
   # f_Osssan(df)  252.788  276.5265  318.70529  287.648  301.5495 2651.492   100
    # f_m0h3n(df) 1422.627 1555.4365 1643.47184 1618.740 1670.7095 4729.827   100
 # f_User2321(df) 2889.738 3000.3055 3148.44916 3037.945 3118.7860 6013.442   100
      # f_dww(df) 2960.740 3086.2790 3206.02147 3143.381 3250.9545 5976.229   100
```

Comment: One point about the benchmarking - almost all the time for f_dww is taken by the conversion to data.table. If you were working with a data.table in the first place (so eliminate the `setDT`), I get microbenchmark mean of 4.45 *nanoseconds*, median of `0` and warning: `Could not measure a positive execution time for 77 evaluations.`

Comment: @dww Yes but I think that's part of the solution. That is, the second part does not work without `setDT(df)`. That's one of the reasons I'm always in favor of `base` R solutions.

Comment: Sure in your case that could be true - i.e. if you are working with data frames for everything else, then the overhead of converting may not be worthwhile for just one calculation. But, in many other instances this is a one time cost that pays back with time savings over multiple data manipulations. Also, sometimes one might be using `fread` to load the data much faster than `read.table`, giving you a data.table at the outset with a saving in time rather than a cost.  Anyway, I just put this out there so others can decide if this is best for them, even if in your case it doesn't make sense.